# Image input through google assistant chat bot using dialogflow

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am building a google assistant chat bot using dialogflow.I want to ask the user to take a picture and upload in between conversation.Is there a way which dialogflow provided to directly trigger intent and also send webhook request with image url.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the an API with FB Messenger app, you can use the Event FACEBOOK_MEDIA. Whenever an upload is made, this will trigger that Event and will get a payload which contains the URL. I am sure there is a specific Event for Google assistant of a similar nature.

Comment: please add some link(s) to documentation supporting you answer if possible